# pandas:groupby('date_x')['outcome'].mean()

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

https://www.kaggle.com/anokas/time-travel-eda

what is these code mean exactly?`groupby('date_x')['outcome'].mean()`，I could not find this in sklearn doc.

```
date_x['Class probability'] = df_train.groupby('date_x')['outcome'].mean()
date_x['Frequency'] = df_train.groupby('date_x')['outcome'].size()
date_x.plot( secondary_y='Frequency',figsize=(22, 10))
```

thanks!

Comment: you can find it in `pandas` documentation. Pandas tutorial on grouping might help. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for aggregate by `size` for length of groups and `mean` per groups which are grouping by column `date_x`:

```
d = {'mean':'Class probability','size':'Frequency'}
df = df_train.groupby('date_x')['outcome'].agg(['mean','size']).rename(columns=d)

df.plot( secondary_y='Frequency',figsize=(22, 10))
```

For more information check [applying multiple functions at once](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once).

Sample:

```
d = {'date_x':pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-01-01',
                              '2015-01-02','2015-01-02']),
     'outcome':[20,30,40,50,60]}
df_train = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df_train)
      date_x  outcome
0 2015-01-01       20 ->1.group
1 2015-01-01       30 ->1.group
2 2015-01-01       40 ->1.group
3 2015-01-02       50 ->2.group
4 2015-01-02       60 ->2.group

d = {'mean':'Class probability','size':'Frequency'}
df = df_train.groupby('date_x')['outcome'].agg(['mean','size']).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
            Class probability  Frequency
date_x                                  
2015-01-01                 30          3
2015-01-02                 55          2
```

Comment: sure ! one last thing please check.. at last why Class probability is 30/55,is it supposed to be 40/60?

Comment: No, because there are 2 groups - first 3 lines with same date `2015-01-01` and mean is `(20+30+40) / 3 = 30` and `2 last rows` with date `2015-01-02` with `(50 + 60) / 2 = 55`